# React new project dependency on ^6.14.0 || ^8.10.0 || >=9.10.0

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have React cli 2.0.3. I tried create new react project but it stopped with error that you have to have 6.14.0 or 8.10.0 or >9.10.0 version. Placing this query to understand what limitations we will have if we use one version of node or another.

Comment: I would expect that these ones are considered stable and trouble-free for some reason. It's unnecessary that earlier versions may cause problems though.

Answer (score 1):

First of all update your NPM version:

```
 npm install npm@latest -g
```

then install node LTS version again:
https://nodejs.org/en/download/